# Bootstrap Multiple Select Two Side

Tags: jquery, select, twitter-bootstrap

In Bootstrap, is there a plugin for multiple select two side? or tutorial how to create a multiple select two side in the bootstrap, from moving right or left, adjust up or down position. Example in jQuery: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/twosidedmultiselect.html but how in the bootstrap?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[multiselect.js](https://github.com/crlcu/multiselect#multiselect)**. It really makes things simple.

**[With move up/down buttons](http://crlcu.github.io/multiselect/examples/move-up-down.html)**

```js
$('#multiselect').multiselect();
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/crlcu/multiselect/v2.5.1/dist/js/multiselect.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <select name="from[]" id="multiselect" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">Item 1</option>
      <option value="2">Item 2</option>
      <option value="3">Item 3</option>
      <option value="4">Item 4</option>
      <option value="5">Item 5</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button type="button" id="multiselect_rightAll" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></i></button>
    <button type="button" id="multiselect_rightSelected" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
    <button type="button" id="multiselect_leftSelected" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></button>
    <button type="button" id="multiselect_leftAll" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <select name="to[]" id="multiselect_to" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple"></select>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <button type="button" id="multiselect_move_up" class="btn btn-block"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></i></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <button type="button" id="multiselect_move_down" class="btn btn-block col-sm-6"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation on the bootstrap website for what you need:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Have a look at Inline checkboxes, Inline form or simply even just using the boostrap span* to arrange your select items e.g

```
<div class="row">

<div class="span1">select item 1</div>
<div class="span1">select item 2</div>

</div>
```

This would align two items side by side in two span1 divs.